# Get-ChildItem not working when running PowerShell script from C#

Tags: c#, powershell

I have a PowerShell script that is using the `Get-ChildItem` cmdlet to get a list of files from a remote folder (the command taking long time because it a big folder).
all working good when i am running the script on the server
The script:

```bsh
$serverip = someremoteip
$mainbackuplocation= someremotelocation
$folder = someremotefolder

$remotefolder = Get-ChildItem "\\$serverip\\d$\\$mainbackuplocation\\$folder\\wwwroot" |
                Out-File d:\log.txt
```

But if I am trying to run the script through C# there is no output at all to the file.

```cs
SecureString securepassword = String2SecureString(password);
PSCredential credential = new PSCredential(userName, securepassword);
WSManConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new WSManConnectionInfo(target,shell,credential);
Runspace remote = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(connectionInfo);
remote.Open();
PowerShell PowerShellInstance = PowerShell.Create();
PowerShellInstance.Runspace = remote;
PowerShellInstance.AddScript("D:\\backup\\test.ps1");
var result = PowerShellInstance.Invoke();
```

I can see that the log file is created on the server, so the PowerShell script is running, but the dir command does nothing.

Would like to know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Perhaps the infamous [2nd hop problem](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2012/11/14/enable-powershell-second-hop-functionality-with-credssp/), since you're running the script remotely from the C# code?

Comment: dont think so because the script is running on the server .. i just starting it from the c#

Comment: `target` is not a different host? Does `userName` have admin permissions on `$serverip`?

Comment: all working good when i am running the script on the server
so all variables all permission are working 

pc1 - is running the c# code
pc2 - is running the ps1 script 
and the script getting the the file list from pc3

Comment: So basically, yes, you're running into the 2nd hop problem. Did you actually bother reading the link in my first comment?

Comment: i will give it a try and update .. thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you're using exactly this code that you write above - there is a small bag.
You have no space after Get-ChildItem - and becouse of this bug - the log.txt file is not created.

Try:

```
$remotefolder = Get-ChildItem "\\$serverip\\d$\\$mainbackuplocation\\$folder\\wwwroot" | Out-File d:\log.txt
```

Comment: thanks but this is not the problem  updated the post with the correct command
(the script is working ok on the server)
i think its something with the time it toke to run the command.. its a big remote folder and its taking some time to write all the files to the log